# To detect and trigger event - Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a barcode scanner. So when the barcode is scanned using a gun, the value normally is entered to textfield placed on the screen.

So I have made an excel macro. And when the barcode is scanned, the text appears on the cell ending with the `new line` character (text+"\r\n" is provided by the scanner itself). So an event is triggered and does the rest.

The problem is that the event is only triggered with a new line character. What if the barcode scanner didn't provide `\r\n` after every barcode output. How do I deal with such situations?
How do I detect it and trigger event?

Comment: `SendKeys` could help simulate a return-key-press, triggering your event. Not sure how you'd detect input though.

Comment: from my (limited) work with bar code guns, there was a setting on the gun to determine if CR/LF was entered after the code. A bar code itself tends not to have new line characters

Comment: @SeanCheshire but that again is hardware dependent. Telling/Explaining clients would be pain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a userform to take the input, you can use the `keydown` or `keypress` events to detect keys pressed. You would have to know what the end condition of the barcode would be, so you know when to send the value to the cell to be processed.

Keydown will give you shift state, and also capture pageup/pagedown/other special keys

```
Private Sub UserForm_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
    ByVal Shift As Integer)
```

Keypress will only work with keys that produce a typeable character

```
Private Sub UserForm_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
```

Without userforms, you will have to rely on enter/newline to trigger the `Change` event in the worksheet

Answer (score 0):

add a Worksheet_Change event as follows into the sheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Add code here to check for
    ' new line and add if not present

End Sub
```

Or if you have the data in a Userform textbox then use the following:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    ' Add code here to check for
    ' new line and add if not present

End Sub
```

Comment: this won't work when enter is not pressed. if the cell is still in edit mode, Worksheet_Change event is not fired, as `ESC` can still be pressed to abort the change

Comment: any update to the s/s will trigger the change event. Im not familiar with barcode machines and any edge cases but if the data is in a textbox of a userform you can use the change event of the textbox